# YOCTO - headers are searched in host's path

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I try to add a package recipe that depends on `libsoc`.
My bb file has `DEPENDS = "libsoc"` and `RDEPENDS = "libsoc"`

In my Makefile I have `CFLAGS = -I/usr/include/`  , when running bitbake I get the error:

```
ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| gcc -I/usr/include/  -o tsl235r_nolibs.o -c tsl235r_nolibs.c
| tsl235r_nolibs.c:6:25: fatal error: libsoc_gpio.h: No such file or 
directory
```

But the header does exist in 
`~/oe-rpb/build-rpb/tmp-rpb-glibc/sysroots/dragonboard-410c/usr/include/libsoc_gpio.h`

For the experiment, I copied `libsoc_gpio.h` to my host's `/usr/include` 
and did not got this error, So yocto searched the header in my host's `/usr/include`. Running `bitbake -e mygpio | grep -i -E  "^sysroot"` 
I get:

```
SYSROOT_DIRS_BLACKLIST="     /usr/share/man     /usr/share/doc     /usr/share/info     /usr/share/locale     /usr/share/applications     /usr/share/fonts     /usr/share/pixmaps "
SYSROOT_DIRS_NATIVE="     /usr/bin     /usr/sbin     /bin     /sbin     /usr/libexec     /etc     /var "
SYSROOT_DESTDIR="/home/dafna/oe-rpb/build-rpb/tmp-rpb-glibc/work/aarch64-linaro-linux/mygpio/1.0+AUTOINC+969889b945-r0/sysroot-destdir"
SYSROOT_PREPROCESS_FUNCS=""
SYSROOT_DIRS="     /usr/include     /usr/lib64     /lib64     /lib     /usr/share "
```

Answer (score 1):

As discussed on IRC your makefile is fundamentally broken.  Use ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${CPPFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS}.